# Generic types with c++ and lua

Tags: c++, lua, luabind

I have an `Entity` class that contains some attributes (pieces of data). These attributes are stored in a map from name => value.

```
class Entity
{
public:
    // Sets the attribute with the specified name.
    void attribute(const std::string& name, const GenericType& value) {
        m_attributes[name] = value;
    }

    // Returns the attribute with the specified name.
    GenericType& attribute(const std::string& name) {
        return m_attributes[name];
    }

    template<typename AttributeType>
    void attribute(const std::string& name, const AttributeType& value) {
        m_attributes[name] = GenericType(value);
    }

    template<typename AttributeType>
    AttributeType& attribute(const std::string& name) {
        return generic_cast<AttributeType>(m_attributes[name]);
    }

private:
    // Map of attributes from name => value.
    std::unordered_map<std::string, GenericType> m_attributes;
}
```

I have a method to create or overwrite an attribute and another method that returns the attribute with the specified name. The first two methods are exposed to Lua. The last two methods are for accessing and modifying attributes from my c++ source code. The problem is that attributes can be of any type. For example, I want to be able to do:

```
entity.attribute("Health", 100)
entity.attribute("Position", Vector3(1,2,3))
entity.attribute("Position").x = 4
```

It should be possible to read and modify attributes both from my c++ source files and from lua scripts. I have previously been using ChaiScript where I used the [Boxed_Value](https://github.com/ChaiScript/ChaiScript/blob/master/include/chaiscript/dispatchkit/boxed_value.hpp) class as my `GenericType`. This worked well but excessive compile times have forced me to look elsewhere.

Is there a way to achieve this with LuaBind (or any other Lua binding library)? The `luabind::object` class looks promising but it takes a `lua_State` pointer in its constructor. This worries me as I feel that the `Entity` class really shouldn't know anything about the Lua state.

Comment: It would have been helpful if you had asked for support with ChaiScript compile times, there are a few techniques to reduce it.

Comment: @lefticus I was able to reduce the compile times and I am still using ChaiScript as I really like the language. The question wasn't really posed exclusively due to the compile times I was getting with ChaiScript. I was also interested in how other language binding libraries approached generic types.

Comment: very good, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LuaBind your entity class doesn't need to know anything about lua state. A Lua binding does not have to be 1-to-1 syntactically identical to the C++ API, as these are quite different languages.

In your case, I would rather split the api into getters and setters. With the shown `Entity` class you might get struggling with making LuaBind do what you want to do unambiguously. What you could do is write a wrapper class for Entity on the C++ side, which would have a LuaBind-conforming, simple interface, i.e. splitting getters and setters using unambiguous names.

[Blufs](https://github.com/d-led/blufs/blob/master/blufs_lib.cpp) is an example, demonstrating what I mean.

As a simple example, [with LuaBridge](https://github.com/d-led/lua_cpp_tryout/blob/27207570/try_luabridge.cpp):

somewhat tricky to create a simple, non hand-rolled binding:

```
class Entity {
    std::map<std::string, int> attributes;

public:
    void attribute(std::string const& key,int value) {
        attributes[key] = value;
    }

    int& attribute(std::string const& key) {
        return attributes[key];
    }
};
```

a wrapper can be bound instead:

```
class EntityWrapper {
    Entity entity;
public:
    void set_int(std::string const& key,int value) {
        entity.attribute(key,value);
    }


    int get_int(std::string const& key) {
        return entity.attribute(key);
    }
};
```

a simple binding:

```
void luabridge_bind(lua_State *L) {
 luabridge::getGlobalNamespace(L)
 .beginClass<EntityWrapper>("Entity")
 .addConstructor<void(*)(), RefCountedPtr<EntityWrapper> /* creation policy */ >()
    .addFunction("get_int", &EntityWrapper::get_int)
    .addFunction("set_int", &EntityWrapper::set_int)
 .endClass()
 ; 
}
```

and in Lua:

```
local e = Entity()
e:set_int("bla",42)
print(e:get_int("bla"))
```

If you need Entity to interact with other APIs, write small wrappers that get the original wrapped object and pass it to other functions.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. My problem is that I don't know the specific attribute types a priori. So I cannot write type-specific getter and setter methods.

Comment: in that case it will be quite hard to have a scripting api, if I'm not mistaken. You will at some point have to enumerate all types used in a script binding. If it's an option, you could create a meta program that will fail to compile if a value converter or a binding is missing from the scripting API. You'll have to modify your generic methods, though, to be part of your meta-program. i.e. `static_assert(has_binding<AttributeType>::value,...)` or whatever should suffice

Comment: @Homar since you're using templates, wouldn't you have to know what types and attributes exist at compile time?

Comment: Yes, at compile time. But I don't want to hard-code getter and setter methods for specific types. If I can get the compiler to generate these then I think that this would be a good solution. I have to register classes with LuaBind, so I need getter and setter methods for all of those types in addition to primitive types.

Comment: Someone will have to know how to convert a `MySuperType` into a set of numbers, strings and booleans, so, there's no way around it. A typical C++ compiler doesn't have that kind of AI. But you can help yourself with meta-programs for generating the value converters in a declarative way. If you can go managed, convert your code into managed code, and you'll get a bit more "for free"

Comment: @Homar that does raise another question, like what if there are certain types/attributes that are valid but currently unused in C++ land? Does that mean it shoud be unavailable in lua land too? Unless you explicitly instantiate that, the compiler isn't going to create it for you.